# Using attribute routing ignores the removal of XmlFormatter MediaTypes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api with several controllers, which use convention-based routing.
However, for one controller I want to use attribute routing, but as soon as I put the RoutePrefix and Route attributes on my controller class and methods, Chrome returns XML instead of JSON, along with the message

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.

The controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("WebVerslaggeving")]
public class WebVerslaggevingController : ApiController
{
    [Route("GetProjectVoorwaardeDocumenten/{projectId:int}/{webVoorwaardeId:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetProjectVoorwaardeDocumenten(int projectId, int webVoorwaardeId)
    {
        var ftpPath = string.Format(@"{0}/Voorwaarden/{1}/", projectId, webVoorwaardeId);

        var fileList = GetFilesFromFolder($@"ftp://{_ftpServer}/{ftpPath}", recursively: true);

        return Ok(fileList);
    }
}
```

In my WebApiConfig, I included these lines:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
```

But apparently that's not working with attribute routing. As soon as I remove the attributes, JSON is returned.

What am I missing?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Are you sure you are reaching the correct controller? Does the debugger stop inside `GetProjectVoorwaardeDocumenten()` when you place a breakpoint there?

Comment: Could you please show us how the default routes are configured?